# Eaten by the net? Crawler survival under this website using python

Tags: python, web-crawler, http-status-code-302

I am making web-crawler to get information from http://www.caam.org.cn/hyzc, but it showed me HTTP Error 302, and I cannot fix it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuVoV.jpg
The picture gives you a rough idea about the special layout of this website in that when you are browsing it, it will pop out a window, telling you that the website is accelerating, for the reason that there are so many people online, and then direct you to that website. As a result, when I use web-crawler, all I get is the information on this window, but nothing on this website. I think this is a good way for the website keeper to get rid of our web crawlers. So I want to ask for your help to get useful information from this website

At first, I used `requests` of python for my web crawler, and I only got information on that window, the results are shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/saff9.jpg
And then I forbad website redirect, I got HTTP Error 303, shown:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMMdV.jpg

This is the latest code I used:

## python

```
import requests
def getpage(url):
    try:
        r= requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=10)
        r.raise_for_status() 
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding 
        return r.text
    except:
        return "try again"
url = "http://www.caam.org.cn/hyzc"
print(getpage(url))
```

The expected outcome of this question is to get useful information from the website http://www.caam.org.cn/hyzc. We may need to deal with the window popped out.

Comment: Can you format your code? If you put 4 spaces before each line, that will be a good start. Since it's python, proper indentation is crucial.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I am a greenhand here and I am learning how to format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this website have some kind of protection against crawlers using requests, the page is not entirely loaded when you send a get request.

You can try to emulate a browser using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.caam.org.cn/hyzc')
print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

`driver.page_source` will contain the page source.

You can learn how to setup selenium webdriver [here](https://pythonspot.com/category/selenium/).

Comment: I am really grateful about your answer. Your lines did not solve my problem, I still got similar results, that only gave information on that window. But selenium you recommended did help me a lot, I added something to delay the closure of my web crawl and this worked. So I want to share my lines in case you meet similar problem in the future:

Answer (score 0):

I added something to delay the closure of my web crawl and this worked. So I want to share my lines in case you meet similar problem in the future:

## python

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
options = Options()   
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)    
driver.get('http://www.caam.org.cn')    
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")    
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, poll_frequency=0.05)    
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(body))    
print(driver.page_source)   
driver.close()
```